# How to retrieve level/depth of current MvcSiteMap node?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I need to find out what level of the menu my current page is on.

I have access to the current node object using razor syntax within my HTML page:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap.CurrentNode
```

Is there a property/method that can show the current nodes depth/level within the sitemap or do I need to write something to traverse the sitemap xml?

Comment: Spent some more time googling this issue and it led me back to my own question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SiteMapPath() to get the breadcrumb menu -

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

Output would be shown like this -

[image]

Reference taken from [here](http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/09/20/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial-2-breadcrumbs/).

EDIT -

Can you try like this in View -

```
var depthCount = Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap.CurrentNode;
@depthCount.Ancestors.Count + 1 // will give you depth count
```

Comment: That gives me something to work with. However, is there a way I can  get a value representing the current node level? For example "Sports News" is on level 3 of the sitemap.